# if we can make ArrayList synchronized then what is the need of Vector?

Tags: java

if we can make ArrayList synchronized then what is the need of Vector?
similarly,
if we can make HashMap synchronized then what is the need of Hashtable?

Comment: It is needed for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reasons why both `Vector` and `ArrayList` exist is historical: the `Vector` class was there in the Java 1, while `ArrayList`s were added in Java 1.2 as a "lighter-weight" alternative. Java keeps `Vector` for backward compatibility; it should not be used unless you want a synchronized version of an `ArrayList`.

Comment: not true at all, if you are using swing , sometimes you need to use vectors xD

Comment: On a side note.  I feel it is unfortunate that things like [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable%28java.util.Vector,%20java.util.Vector%29) used `Vector` instead of `ArrayList`.  I guess it was just that `ArrayList` was not around in the initial development phase of Swing..

Comment: @nachokk, the reason swing components exist is historical as well )))

Comment: @AndrewThompson vector is synchronized by default, yet arraylist is not. using vector helps u avoid concurrency issues.

Comment: @KickButtowski  *"vector is synchronized by default, yet arraylist is not"*  So what?  Is it too much to expect that a constructor from J2SE would make `ArrayList` synchronized if that part of the API requires it?  It does not seem like a valid reason to me.

Comment: @basblinkenlight I could not find any indication in oracel documentation that vector is deprecated. if you did, plz provide me a link. thank you.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I totally understand your point, yet as far as I know arrayList are faster than vector, but I cannot remember in what matter.

Answer (score 0):

Making HashMap using external synchronization helps in avoiding concurrent accesses to the same HashMap. 
HashTable is deprecated since java 1.2 onwards and this is synchronized which accounts in some performance overhead which is why java has supported both the implementations i.e. synchronized and unsynchronized version.